# Snakemake to --export-cwl conversion requires static config/inputs

Tags: snakemake

So I am currently interesting in using Snakemake to convert some snakemake pipelines into CWL using the --export-cwl function, but have come to the realization that this requires that all inputs filenames be predefined in the config file. This means that this cwl workflow is only useful for the current pipeline run and is not capable of being exported as a more general use pipeline that can be adapted to varying config parameters (e.g. I would have to re-run the conversion tool for every single run that ever goes through it). Is this a limitation of the Snakemake conversion tool or CWL? I am not very familiar with CWL so I know very little about it's inner workings. Or is there some workaround that I am not seeing?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, --export-cwl currently exports the currently configured instance of the workflow, in particular concrete jobs. In fact it even directly defines the entire DAG of jobs in CWL (all dependency inference happens in Snakemake). This allows to execute the workflow on a CWL based system. It does not directly allow to port a Snakemake workflow to CWL, in the sense that it could be easily applied to new datasets. The reason is that CWL is less powerful with regards to aggregation patterns than Snakemake (which can leverage full Python for determining the input files of a particular job).

Nevertheless, there is interest in both the Snakemake and CWL team on having a more generic export. This might be limited to certain workflows, or dependent on future improvements of CWL. Any help would be greatly appreciated.